# What should I do to add a domain event after the completion of UnitOfWork?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, abp

I used the ABP vNext framework.I need to publish a domain event when saved an aggregated specified property to the database successfully,but now, the domain event is always triggered before the unit of work is completed.

Code

```
public class Meeting : AggregateRoot<Guid>{
        public Meeting(Guid id, Guid applicantId) : base(id) {
            ApplicantId = applicantId;
            Phase = MeetingPhase.Draft;
            Type = MeetingType.Default;
            TimeAndPlaces = new Collection<TimeAndPlace>();
            InsideAttendees = new Collection<InsideAttendee>();
            MeetingFiles = new Collection<MeetingFile>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 取消会议
        /// </summary>
        public void Cancel() {
            Phase = MeetingPhase.Draft;
            Type = MeetingType.Canceled;
            var cancelData = new MeetingCancelData(this);
            AddLocalEvent(cancelData);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us your relevant codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can contribute to IUnitOfWork.CompletedHandlers handlers.

See https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.Uow/Volo/Abp/Uow/UnitOfWork.cs#L194